# Spacing of a math formula defined by other math formula

Tags: math-mode, phantom, horizontal-spacing

I need to make sure that the spacing of some short math formula (like `$x^2$`) would take exactly the same spacing as some other a bit longer math formula (like `$(x+1)^2-1$`). The result should be `$x^2$` with additional spaces on left and right.

I was hoping that something like `\hphantom{$(x+1)^2-1$}{$x^2$}` would do that, but it looks like `\hphantom` doesn't have a second argument.

Any suggestions?

EDIT.
@projetmbc
Quite often I need to position things in tikz pictures so that the numbers on axes would be at the exact same position as in other pictures, like in the example below (now with egreg's solution it's easy to accomplish that):
[image]

Comment: Gives us a MWE and a picture showing the output expected.

Comment: What is the context of use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\inset}[2]{%
  % #1 = formula to typeset
  % #2 = formula to occupy the space of
  \makebox[\widthof{$#2$}]{$#1$}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text $(x+1)^2-1$ and some text.  

Some text $\inset{x^2+2x}{(x+1)^2-1}$ and some text.  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.